# File is showing as undefined in req.file in server side

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, multer

I am using `multer` to get the file information in server-side from my Register.js `React-hooks`page. 
While setting a breakpoint in server.js, I am able to see `req` information but the file is somehow showing `undefined`.
I have added the client-side and server-side code in my question.

In the multer documentation, I read to get a file is via `req.file`, but I am getting undefined and I am kind of stuck at the moment.

[image]

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var multer  = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/images/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var ext = file.originalname.split('.').pop();
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext);
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.put('/service/player',  upload.single('photo'), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userName = req.body.name;
    const userEmail = req.body.email; 
    const userPhone = req.body.phonenumber;
    const userPassword = req.body.password;
    const userPrivilege = req.body.privilege;
    const userPrivilegeUppercase = userPrivilege.toUpperCase();
    const userImage = req.body.photo;
    const userPosition = req.body.position;
    console.log(req.file);  //file is getting undefined here 

    const playerEmail = await UserModel.count({ where: { email: userEmail } });
    if (playerEmail == 0) {

      if(req.file){   //new code to check the image starts here
        var imageOriginalName = req.body.photo.originalname;
        var imageName = req.body.photo.fieldname;
        var imageMime = req.body.photo.mimetype;
        var imagePath = req.body.photo.path;
        var imageSize = req.body.photo.size;
    } else {
        var imageName = "noimage.png";
    }    //ends here

      //If there is no email found, procced with normal registration here...
      var playerData = {name:userName, email:userEmail, phonenumber:userPhone, password:userPassword, privilege:userPrivilegeUppercase, photo: imagePath, position: userPosition };
      const addPlayer = await UserModel.create(playerData);
      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    } else {
      return res.status(409).json({ message: "Email address already exists !" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

`Register.js`

```
const [formRegister, setRegister] = useState({ _id: '', photo: '', name: '', email: '', phonenumber: '', position: '', privilege: '', password: '' })

 const onChangePicture = e => {
console.log('picture: ', picture);
if (e.target.files.length) {
  setPicture(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
  setRegister({ ...formRegister, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
} else {
  return false;
}
```

};

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setRegister({ ...formRegister, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  const onSubmit = e => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.put('http://localhost:8000/service/player', formRegister);
        console.log("Front End success message:" + res.data.success);
        if (res.data.success) {
          setIsSent(true);
          history.push('/login')
        }
        else {
          console.log(res.data.message);
          setHelperText(res.data.message);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }

return (
<div className="register_player_column_layout_one">
        <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="myForm" encType="multipart/form-data">
            <div className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
              <h2 className="formTitle" >Sign Up</h2>
              <p className="instructionsText">Not registered yet, please register now !</p>
              <div className="register_profile_image">
                <input id="profilePic" name="photo" type="file" onChange={onChangePicture} />
              </div>
              <div className="previewProfilePic" >
                <img alt="" onError={addDefaultSrc} name="previewImage"  className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" src={picture}></img>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="fillContentDiv formElement">
              <label>
                <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name"
                  onChange={onChange}
                  maxLength={30}
                  ref={register({
                    required: "Full name is required",
                    pattern: {
                      value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]{3,30}$/,
                      message: "Full name should have minimum of 3 letters"
                    }
                  })}
                />
                <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.name && errors.name.message}</span>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"
                  onChange={onChange}
                  ref={register({
                    required: "Email is required",
                    pattern: {
                      value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                      message: "Invalid email address"
                    }
                  })}
                />
                <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.email && errors.email.message}</span>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="phonenumber" type="text" placeholder="Mobile"
                  onChange={onChange}
                  maxLength={11}
                  ref={register({
                    required: "Phone number is required",
                    pattern: {
                      value: /^[0-9\b]+$/,
                      message: "Invalid phone number"
                    }
                  })}
                />
                <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.phonenumber && errors.phonenumber.message}</span>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="position" type="text" placeholder="Position" 
                onChange={onChange} 
                maxLength={30}
                ref={register({
                  pattern: {
                    value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]{2,30}$/,
                    message: "Position should have minimum of 2 letters"
                  }
                })}
                />
                <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.position && errors.position.message}</span>
              </label>
              <label>
                <div className="select" >
                  <select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} name="privilege" id="select" onChange={onChange}>
                    <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose an option</option>
                    <option value="player">PLAYER</option>
                    <option value="admin">ADMIN</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="password" type="password" placeholder="eg: P@ssW0rd"
                  onChange={onChange}
                  minLength={4}
                  maxLength={30}
                  ref={register({
                    required: "Password is required",
                    pattern: {
                      value: /^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]+$/,
                      message: "Password begin with a letter and includes number !"
                    }
                  })}
                />
                <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.password && errors.password.message}</span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <label>
              <span className="registerValidationText">{helperText}</span>
            </label>
            <div className="submitButtonDiv formElement" style={{ margin: isError ? '65px 0 20px 0' : '20px 0 20px 0' }}>
              <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Register</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First line on multer doc :**
>
> Multer is a node.js middleware for handling `multipart/form-data`

So, you need pass data as `multipart/form-data` but, you are not passing it, its just `json` object file is not even being passed, hence you are not getting the file on server side

Example code snippet of how it should look like :

```
const formData = new FormData();

// also append the other fields needs to be passed
for(let key in formRegister) {
  formData.append(key,formRegister[key]);
}

formData.append('photo',file); // <--- append your file

const config = {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' // <-- Set header for 
    }
}

axios.put('http://localhost:8000/service/player', formData , config);
```

Comment: /src/components/Register.js
  Line 49:25:  'file' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 50:24:  Unexpected use of 'name'  no-restricted-globals

Comment: ..I am getting above error..Should I need to define the variables like file, name, email, phonenumber again ?

Comment: file is file object that you need to maintain while uploading file, check this https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-file-upload-proper-server-side-nodejs-easy/

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined `const file = e.target.photo;
const name = e.target.name;
const email = e.target.email;....`

Comment: I have tried to get the fields values like above to append to formData..but still not looking good ! May I know what I am doing incorrect here ?

Comment: @soccerway, create a working demo of what you are trying.

Comment: Created a codesandbox link > https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-moon-hrs6k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you check if you can access this one

Comment: @soccerway, check this : https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-murdock-0yn0z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Showing an error at line 53 in the Sandbox linke provided ...error >> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: You can ignore that, its just ternery operator, you can use simple if also, check again, reload same link

Comment: Sorry while submit it says` Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined
onSubmit
C:/Project/soccerpep/src/components/Register.js:51
  48 | 
  49 | if (picture) formData.append("photo", picture);`

Comment: Are you using photo variable anywhere? Error is of photo variable please check, codesandbox is working fine only issue in local url apart from that it will work, you can check the network tab, or share your updated code again

Comment: No I am not using the variable nowhere else. I have share the updated codesandbox link

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: Sorry update the link here .. https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-moon-hrs6k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @soccerway, this is old code, please refer my code it's updated, I've already removed and made other changes in your code, but in your code it still shows old code, you can compare the file and check the changes

Comment: Thank you Vivek, now I can see req.file coming up, but unfortunately my preview is broken if i add `setPicture(e.target.files[0]);` as suggested. The following one is old code whcih displays preview ...//setPicture(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
  setPicture(e.target.files[0]);

Comment: you can store the preview in another variable, `setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));`

Comment: All good accepted and upvoted @Vivek. Wonderful support,

Comment: Are you able to provide advise on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62386337/pass-data-between-react-hooks