# Pass data between react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

How can I pass the data from one `React hooks` form (*component*) to another component. For example if I need player `name and photo` pass from `Profile.js` and make it available in `Navigation.js`, how can i do that ?

`Player.js`

```
import React, { useContext , useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from "axios";
import UserProfileContext from '../context';

const Profile = () => {

  const { setData } = useContext(UserProfileContext);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [picture, setPicture] = useState('');
  const [playerProfile, setPlayerProfile] = useState([]);
  const loginUserEmail = localStorage.getItem('loginEmail');
  const [updateProfile, setUpdateProfile] = useState({ _id: '', photo: '', name: '', email:'', phonenumber: '', position: '', password: '' })
  const [isSent, setIsSent] = useState(false);
  const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState('');
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();
  const history = useHistory();

  const onChangePicture = e => {
    console.log('picture: ', picture);
    if (e.target.files.length) {
      setPicture(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  // If no profile image is being uploaded, to avoid the broken display of image, display a default image.
  const addDefaultSrc = e => {
    e.target.src = '/images/default-icon.png';
  }

  // Pass the id to the handler so you will know which item id changing.
  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    e.persist();
    let itemIndex;
    const targetPlayer = playerProfile.find((player, index) => {
      console.log({ player, id, index });
      itemIndex = index; // Track the index so you can use it to update later.
      return player.id === id;
    });

    console.log({ targetPlayer, id, e });

    const editedTarget = {
      ...targetPlayer,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    const tempPlayers = Array.from(playerProfile);
    tempPlayers[itemIndex] = editedTarget;
    /*
    // Alternatively:: you can just  map over the array if you dont want to track the index
    const tempPlayers = playerProfile.map((profile, index) => {
      return profile.id === id ? editedTarget : profile;
    });
    */
    setPlayerProfile(tempPlayers);
    setUpdateProfile({ ...updateProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }); // this is added just to see if its working
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const params = {
          email: loginUserEmail,
        };
      const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/profile', {params});
        setPlayerProfile(res.data.playerProfile);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = () => {
    setDisabled(disabled);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const params = {
          email: loginUserEmail,
        };
        const data = {photo: updateProfile.photo, name: updateProfile.name, email: updateProfile.email, phonenumber: updateProfile.phonenumber, position: updateProfile.position, password: updateProfile.password}
        const res = await Axios.put('http://localhost:8000/service/profile', data, {params}); 
        console.log("Front End update message:" + res.data.success);
        if (res.data.success) {
          setIsSent(true);
          history.push('/')
        }
        else {
          console.log(res.data.message);
          setHelperText(res.data.message);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }

  return (
    <div className="register_wrapper">
      <div className="register_player_column_layout_one">
        <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="myForm">
            {
              playerProfile.map(({ id, photo, name, email, phonenumber, position, privilege, password }) => (
                <div key={id}>
                  <div className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
                    <h2 className="formTitle">Profile</h2>
                    <div className="register_profile_image">
                      <input id="profilePic" name="photo" type="file" onChange={onChangePicture} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="previewProfilePic" >
                      <img alt="" onError={addDefaultSrc} name="previewImage" className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" src={photo} onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}></img>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="fillContentDiv formElement">
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="name" type="text" value={name} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      maxLength={30}
                      ref={register({
                        required: "Full name is required", 
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]{3,30}$/,
                          message: "Full name should have minimum of 3 letters"
                        }
                      })}
                      />
                      <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.name && errors.name.message}</span>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="email" type="text" value={email} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      disabled={disabled}
                      />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="phonenumber" type="text" value={phonenumber} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      maxLength={11}
                      ref={register({
                        required: "Phone number is required",
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[0-9\b]+$/,
                          message: "Invalid phone number"
                        }
                       })}
                      />
                      <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.phonenumber && errors.phonenumber.message}</span>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="position" type="text" value={position} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      maxLength={30}
                      ref={register({
                        pattern: {
                          value: /^[a-zA-Z\s]{2,30}$/,
                          message: "Position should have minimum of 2 letters"
                        }
                      })}
                      />
                      <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.position && errors.position.message}</span>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <div className="select" >
                        <select name="privilege" id="select" value={privilege} onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}>
                          {/*<option selected disabled>Choose an option</option> */}
                          <option value="player">PLAYER</option>
                          {/*<option value="admin">ADMIN</option>*/}
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="password" type="password" value={password} 
                      onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}
                      minLength={4}
                      maxLength={30}
                      ref={register({
                      required: "Password is required",
                      pattern: {
                        value: /^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]+$/,
                        message: "Password begin with a letter and includes number !"
                      }
                      })}
                      />
                      <span className="registerErrorTextFormat">{errors.password && errors.password.message}</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <label>
                    <span className="profileValidationText">{helperText}</span>
                  </label>
                  <div className="submitButtonDiv formElement">
                    <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Save</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            }
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Navigation.js`

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { NavLink, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserProfileContext from '../context';


const Navigation = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const { data } = useContext(UserProfileContext);

    const divStyle = {
        float:'left',
        color: '#64cad8', 
        padding: '0px 0px 0px 10px',
        font:'Lucida, sans-serif'
      };

    function logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('loginEmail')
        localStorage.removeItem('Privilege')
        history.push('/login')
        window.location.reload(true);
      }

    return localStorage.getItem('loginEmail') &&
        <div className="App">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <nav className="siteNavigation_nav_links">
                <div className="clubLogo landing"style={divStyle}><b>Southside Soccer</b></div>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/profile">Profile</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_login_link" to="/login" onClick={logout}>Logout</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_login_link" to='/aboutus'>About us</NavLink>
                <div className="profileImage nav menu">
                <span>{data.name}</span>|<img src=""></img>
                </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
}

export default Navigation;
```

`App.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import "./CSSModules/home.css";
import "./CSSModules/register.css";
import "./CSSModules/login.css";
import "./CSSModules/aboutus.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Aboutus from "./components/Aboutus";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";
import { ProtectedRoute } from "./components/protected.route";
import UserProfileContext from './context';

var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    id: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    photo: '',
  });

  return (
   <UserProfileContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <>
     <Navigation />
      <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/aboutus" component={Aboutus} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </>
   </BrowserRouter>
  </UserProfileContext.Provider>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App, null),
  document.getElementById("root")
);

export default App;
```

`context.js`

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createContext();
```

Comment: You need to `lift your state up` - https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html - or use something like `context` - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned in the comments, one option is to [left your application's state up](http://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) (and that should be the preferred option for simple state).

In practice, that would look like:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Profile from './Profile';

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation name={name} />
      <hr />
      <Profile name={name} setName={setName} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Profile.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

const Profile = ({ name, setName }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Profile: {name}</div>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

**Navigation.js:**

```
import React from 'react';

const Navigation = ({ name }) => {
  return <div>Navigation: {name}</div>;
};

export default Navigation;
```

**Edit:** After a closer look at your code, I think using context API makes more sense in this case.

Try the following:

**context.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createContext();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import './styles.css';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import UserProfileContext from './context';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    id: 'player-1',
    name: 'Player One',
    age: 25,
    photo: 'rose.JPG',
  });

  return (
    <UserProfileContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </UserProfileContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**components/Navigation.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import UserProfileContext from '../context';

const Navigation = () => {
  const { data } = useContext(UserProfileContext);

  const divStyle = {
    float: 'left',
    color: '#64cad8',
    padding: '0px 0px 0px 10px',
    font: 'Lucida, sans-serif',
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <nav className="siteNavigation_nav_links">
          <div className="clubLogo landing" style={divStyle}>
            <b>Soccer</b>
          </div>

          <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/profile">
            Profile
          </NavLink>

          <div className="profileImage nav menu">
            <span>{data.name}</span> | <img alt="" src={data.photo} />
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

**components/Profile.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import UserProfileContext from '../context';

const Profile = () => {
  const { setData } = useContext(UserProfileContext);
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(setData)}>
        <b>Profile</b>
        <input name="id" ref={register} />
        <input name="name" ref={register} />
        <input name="age" ref={register} />
        <button type="submit" className="submitButton">
          Click
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Comment: Thank you in my real example I am getting lots of error when I change as per suggested.

Comment: My App.js looks as below :`var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

const App = () => (
  
  <BrowserRouter>
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <ProtectedRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <ProtectedRoute path="/aboutus" component={Aboutus} />
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(App, null),
  document.getElementById("root")
);`

Comment: Thank you, in my case Profile.js has got my login player data loaded from database :  `const [playerProfile, setPlayerProfile] = useState([]);`   and below is my axios get >> ` useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const params = {
          email: loginUserEmail,
        };
      const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/profile', {params});
        setPlayerProfile(res.data.playerProfile);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);`

Comment: I have added my updated `App.js, Navigation.js and Profile.js` as suggested. Player data is available in Profile.js and how can we pass `const [playerProfile, setPlayerProfile] = useState([]);` into useContext(UserProfileContext);  ? When i tried const { setPlayerProfile} = useContext(UserProfileContext) instead of setData,  it is throwing error that error it already declared ..

Comment: I have updated my question with updated `App.js, Navigation.js and Profile.js` with my original code.

Comment: Why are we creating `const [data, setData] = useState({ .....`  in `App.js`, because the data that we need to grab is available in Profile.js ?

Comment: @soccerway the reason is that you want that data to also be available in `Navigation.js`, so one way is to left the state up and pass the data to components that need it via props. A second way is using React context API.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `react-redux` for global state handling or pass a callback function from `Navigation.js` to `Profile.js`.

Comment: Is there any other way other than using redux ?

Comment: Ofc. for this single use I would suggest you to lift your state reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html other than if you use it more often go for React Context.

Answer (score 0):

Use React's built in context API. Wrap your App in context provider, then you can use useContext hook to access state, dispatch state updates between components.

**App level setup - one time**

```
// Define Context
const AppContext = React.createContext()

// Define initial state
const initialState = {}

// Define Reducer
const Reducer = (state, dispatch) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "ACTION_TYPE": return {...state, prop: action.payload}
    default: return state
  }
}


//Wrap main App in context, pass state from React's useReducer hook
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState)
<AppContext.Provider data={{
  state,
  dispatch
}}>
  <ReactAppMainWrapper />
</AppContext.Provider>
```

**Component level**

```
const {state, dispatch} = useContext(AppContext);

// to update state call dispatch from anywhere, all components consuming state will be updated

dispatch({
   type: "ACTION_TYPE",
   payload: "new_value"
})
```

**Explanation**

The state serves as redux like store, available in the entire app.

In any component, import AppContext and use React's builtin useContext hook to interact with store from the component.

Data object passed in Context provider above is available from this.

Comment: Can you provide me a simple example if possible.